# pygame pixel processing is slow

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to iterate through the numpy array and assigning a 0 - 255 value based on the distance to the mouse.
`WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` are in this case set to 400 and `GRID[]` is a numpy matrix with `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` dimensions.
I'm using the `window.set_at()` function to draw each pixel on the screen with the color stored in the numpy matrix, I'm getting about 5 FPS.
Is there a more efficient way to handle this type of pixel processing,  or should I switch to something like c++ & SFML

```
    #update pixels
    for y in range(HEIGHT):
        for x in range(WIDTH):
            #get color based on distance to mouse; 0 -> 255
            mousePosition = pg.mouse.get_pos()
            dx = mousePosition[0] - x
            dy = mousePosition[1] - y
            d = math.sqrt(abs(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2))

            #constraining the distance value between 0 - 255
            c = min(max(d, 0), 255)

            GRID[x,y] = c


    #draw pixels
    for y in range(HEIGHT):
        for x in range(WIDTH):
            c = GRID[x,y]
            window.set_at((x, y), (c, c, c))
```

Comment: Surely you don't need to get the mouse-position again after updating each pixel? Can't you get it once, outside and before the loops? And if that works, you should be able to vectorise the whole thing.

Comment: This is a very "brute force" algorithm.  Do you have to check *every* pixel?  Perhaps you could somehow separate out the `x` and `y` component, so if the mouse only moves in one dimension, there's only O(N) iterations, rather than O(N²).  You can make some minor speedups, like: `(x * x)` always seems to be faster than `(x ** 2)`.  But it's the algorithm that's the real problem.  Maybe you could draw a bunch of circles around the mouse cursor - at least the circle algorithm will support axes of symmetry, etc.  A slow algorithm will be slow no matter what the language.

Answer (score 1):

> pygame pixel processing is slow

Yes it is.  So don't process pixels.

Given your colour resolution of 256, this means we're really dealing with a bunch of coloured circles around the mouse cursor.  By considering only these circles, you're specifically *not processing* all those other pixels that can *never* be anything other than colour-zero.

[image: screenshot]

The code below implements the program by drawing circles about the mouse cursor where the circle radius is the known distance.  So we're drawing a circle in the same "distance-colour".  Assuming the circle is drawn using the [midpoint circle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm), this means that it only needs to calculate 1/8 of the pixels, and the rest are just quadrant (octant?) reflected about an axis of circle-symmetry.

```
import pygame
import random

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH      = 600
WINDOW_HEIGHT     = 600

###
### MAIN
###
pygame.init()
window  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )
pygame.display.set_caption("Mouse Distance")


# Main loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            running = False

    # Paint the screen in a gradient centred about the mouse
    window.fill( ( 0, 0, 0 ) )   # max distance
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    for distance in range( 255 ):
        colour = ( 255-distance, 255-distance, 255-distance )
        pygame.draw.circle( window, colour, mouse_pos, distance, 2 )  # use a width of 2 so there's no "holes"

    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

I don't have time to make the change right now, but this example *should* draw to a surface, and then `blit()` that surface to the window for painting.  That way we only need to re-compute the surface when the mouse moves.

Comment: Was there a specific reason to invert the colour?

Comment: @importrandom - Nope, I didn't notice it was a certain way.

Comment: Does `pygame.HWSURFACE` make any difference for you? The [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) say that the flag is obsolete in pygame 2. I had some trouble tinkering with the `OPENGL` flag so I discarded that approach.

Comment: @importrandom - I didn't know it was now obsolete.  Will edit.

Comment: I'm confused, `DOUBLEBUF` is also obsolete, but I couldn't get `OPENGL` to work without it.

Comment: @importrandom - I can't really tell.  I write answers on an old Linux VM (Ubuntu 18, pygame 1.9.2) running under windows, at work, answering while waiting for compiles.  So any sort of  "hardware" available to pygame is probably 2-levels abstracted.  :D

Answer (score 1):

What constitutes fast enough?

Tidying up your code to create a minimal example with your 400x400 resolution:

```
import math
import time
import pygame
width, height = 400, 400

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
screen.fill(pygame.Color("black"))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Graphics
    # update pixels
    start = time.time()
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            distance = math.sqrt( (mx - x)**2 + (my - y)**2 )  # 2.2 FPS 0.455s 
            #constrain the distance value between 0 - 255
            c = min(max(distance, 0), 255)
            screen.set_at((x, y), (c, c, c))
            
    # Update Screen
    pygame.display.set_caption(f"FPS: {clock.get_fps():.1f} Pixel Processing {time.time() - start:.3f} s")
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

This results in 2.2 FPS on my PC.
The Python math module has a function that calculates the [hypotenuse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot), so it's probably a little more optimised. Change the calculation to:

```
distance = math.hypot(mx - x, my - y)
```

This increases my frame rate by 50% to 3, probably still too slow.

We can be smarter about the pixels we modify, instead of clamping the distance to 255, fill the screen with white and then if the distance is greater than 255, don't change the pixel.

```
screen.fill(pygame.Color("white"))
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        distance = math.hypot(mx - x, my - y)
        if distance <= 255:  # don't set far pixels
            c = round(distance)
            screen.set_at((x, y), (c, c, c))
```

This increases my frame rate to 12 when the mouse is in the corner, 8 in the middle. Perhaps this is approaching usable.

If you look at the documentation for [surface.set_at()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_at), it says that using `get_at()` and `set_at` is too slow and recommends using [PixelArray](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html#pygame.PixelArray) or [SurfArray](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#module-pygame.surfarray). So we can create a SurfArray:

```
surfarray = pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(screen)
```

Then to set the pixel values, we replace `screen.set_at()`:

```
surfarray[x, y] = (c,c,c)
```

Surprisingly and unfortunately this doesn't change the frame rate significantly. Maybe this requires hardware acceleration.

I also tried manually [locking](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.lock) the surface before iterating through the pixels as suggested in the docs, but this made no significant improvement.

So lets consider what we're doing, drawing the same circle wherever the mouse is every frame. It will be faster if we draw the circle once, and then blit it every frame centered on the mouse position. To create the circle, it's similar to what's already been done:

```
size = 255 * 2
dist_image = pygame.Surface((size, size), pygame.SRCALPHA)
for y in range(size):
    for x in range(size):
        distance = math.hypot(255 - x, 255 - y)
        if distance <= 255:
            c = round(distance)
            dist_image.set_at((x, y), (c, c, c))
```

Then our graphics update logic becomes:

```
screen.fill(pygame.Color("white"))
dist_rect =  dist_image.get_rect(center=pygame.mouse.get_pos())
screen.blit(dist_image, dist_rect)
```

This runs at 60 FPS (max) and takes almost no processing time:
[image: Distance Circle]